# How to get the values from date picker in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I am using Angular4 material date pickers, below is my code for date picker

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

My question is how to get the value of the date picker when I am choosing a date from date picker in my `Component`?

Comment: simply use `[(ngModel)]="someVariable"` in input filed

Comment: I don't need advice anything from you which is not related to code.I just conveyed my message rather than getting point from edit do write codes

Answer (score 2):

You could use a reactive form. First set up formBuilder Like this

```
constructor(  private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

Now generate FormControls

```
public generateFormContorls() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      due_date: ['']
    });
```

Now you need to set formControlName=""due_date". like this

```
  <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="dueDate" formControlName="due_date" (click)="dueDate.open()"
              (focus)="dueDate.open()">
            <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-datepicker #dueDate></md-datepicker>
```

Now get the value by simply using this.

```
console.log(" value:",this.myForm.get("due_date").value);
```